# free basic compiler error 23: File not found, libsupc++.a

Tags: 12.04, compiling

I am trying to compile a simple a hello word QBASIC program in ubutu 12.04. downloaded and installed as instructed here. http://www.freebasic.net/get

```
print "hello word"
```

I compiled it.

```
 fbc hello.bas
```

But I got the following error.

hello.bas() error 23: File not found, libsupc++.a

ld: cannot find -lncurses
ld: cannot find -lsupc++

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install additional packages. Please see:-

http://www.freebasic.net/wiki/wikka.php?wakka=CompilerInstalling

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.